# Modify the Y-axis in the metrics explorer chart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm struggling in modifying the y-axis of the metrics explorer chart. Please have a look at the attached screenshot. As you can see, 1221 is the response time, and data on Y-axis is displaying as per the latency.

I want to achieve the following:

- Y-axis should be display based on the API response time. As 1221 is displayed in the screenshot.

[Google cloud metrics graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRcDo.png)

[Metric logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luRjd.png)

I have also used distribution metrics.  But again I am getting the different time series rather than the correct response time on the y-axis. As you can see in Link 1(i.e metric explorer) in the graph the response time 1 got is 1304.2 rather than 1042 (Link 2)

1. [Link 1](https://07317209644548377815.googlegroups.com/attach/93e08071a26e/distribution_metric_explorer.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrE6mFlYD4NiZDML0XsmQSubahzoMvUWLjTVpJ6Rpnzda7lr2VazD-eF62xMjY6yCgDGJuabeMRFaMHf89OeAlTIW0LYsC93tMySoX2oWzRqmdu2zz4)
2. [Link 2](https://07317209644548377815.googlegroups.com/attach/93e08071a26e/distribution_metric.png?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrE-9t0t7eQX6ZC2J_gOHgvzVtyQexqlorZcL3GgKgQjFcFzcScCv-E0TL-NTnJ4h62ESD-je5ewwZ1o3_cgGlxGCBM88yB_PNVpYs_m4v2UcffODYE)

Comment: Can you provide more details on your setup and metric?
Also, have you tried changing "group by function" from 'count' to 'max'?

Comment: So @SergiuszRusiecki from what I understand, he is trying to measure responsetime from an endpoint and is using a logger that provides that data point in the JSON payload. And from the graph showing, the axis are strangely distributed since he probably want to have the y-axis to show a range of the response time possbilities. So that he can notice any spikes. But rakesh has to support this statement

Comment: @vonGohren I totally agree with your statement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're counting log entries with a label (separate count) for each response time.

If you want the response time to be the value of the metric (i.e. to be on the axis), then you probably want the distribution of response times: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics

Comment: I have updated the details.Please have a look